# Why is the haskell function not working correctly?

Tags: haskell, fractions

I am wondering which mistake the following Haskellcode has!

```
f :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
f x y
 | x > y = x - y
 | otherwise = x + y
call = f 3.5 2.0
```

I was trying to solve the problem but I couldnt find a solution since 3.5 and 2.0 are floats and that should work with the fractional type.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When posting non-working code as you did, it's usually a good idea to specify what's going wrong. If the code is producing the wrong result (or a run-time error), post the wrong result and your expected one. If the code does not compile, post the full compiler error. In this way you make it much simpler to answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you are comparing the two items `x` and `y`, and this is not exported by the `Fractional` typeclass or any of its superclasses, you need to make constrain it to `Ord` as well:

```
f :: (Ord a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> a
f x y
   | x > y = x - y
   | otherwise = x + y
```

`Float`, `Double`, etc. are all instances of `Ord` so we can compare the values, so then we get:

```
ghci> f 3.5 2.0
1.5
```

Comment: Alternatively, use [`(RealFrac a)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:RealFrac), which contains almost all of the types that are both `Ord` and `Fractional`.